# how to pass a value to c++ from python and back?

Tags: c++, python

i would like to pass values from python to a c++ program for an encryption from inside a python program and then return the value from there to the python program . how to do it?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use some existing Unix-style command line utility that reads from stdin and writes to stdout, you can use [`subprocess.Popen`](http://docs.python.org/library/subprocess.html#using-the-subprocess-module) by using [`Popen.communicate()`](http://docs.python.org/library/subprocess.html#popen-objects):

```
import subprocess

p = subprocess.Popen(["/your/app"], stdin=subprocess.PIPE, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
output = p.communicate(input)[0]
```

Answer (score 0):

As said msw in the other post, the proper solution is using PyObject.
If you want to have a two-way communication between C++ & Python, Boost Python would be interesting for you. Take a look at website [Boost Python](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_61_0/libs/python/doc/html/index.html),

This post would also be interesting:
[How to expose a C++ class to Python without building a module](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18442403/how-to-expose-a-c-class-to-python-without-building-a-module)