# How to expose a C++ class to Python without building a module

Tags: c++, python, swig, boost-python

I want to know if there is any way to expose a C++ class to Python but without building an intermediate shared library.

Here is my desirable scenario. For example I have following C++ class:

```
class toto
     {
     public:
        toto(int iValue1_, int iValue2_): iValue1(iValue1_), iValue2(iValue2_) {}
        int Addition(void) const {if (!this) return 0; return iValue1 + iValue2;}

      private:
        int iValue1;
        int iValue2;
     };
```

I would like to convert somehow this class (or its intance) to a PyObject* in order to send it as paremter (args) to for example PyObject_CallObject:

```
PyObject* PyObject_CallObject(PyObject* wrapperFunction, PyObject* args)
```

In the other hand in my python side, I'll have a wrapperFunction which gets the pointer on my C++ class (or its instance) as parameter and it calls its methods or uses its properties:

```
def wrapper_function(cPlusPlusClass):
    instance = cPlusPlusClass(4, 5)
    result = instance.Addition()
```

As you can see, I don't really need/want to have a separate shared library or build a module by boost python. All that I need is to find a way to convert a C++ code to PyObject and send it to python. I cannot find a way to do that by C python libraries, boost or SWIG.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand exactly what you want. Boost.Python has `boost::python::object::ptr`, which returns a `PyObject*` -- is this what you were looking for?

Comment: I believe it's possible to access C/C++ via `ctypes`, but it might be a difficult task to expose a C++ class.

Comment: @PaulManta: Thanks for the answer. What I want consists in 3 steps: Step1: encapsulate a C++ class in PyObject pointer.Step2 send this pointer to a python function. Step3. using this C++ pointer in python (i.e. calling its methods). So could you please be more pragmatic & tell be by an example how can I encapsulate C++ code to object::ptr?

Comment: Do you want to use the Python interpreter from your C++ code? Have you had a look at this question: http://stackoverflow.com/q/8225934/1025391 ?

Comment: Thank you @moooeeeep! yes you are right, actually this answer is pretty similar to what I'm trying to do. I updated the answer. In addition, we can get rid of boost::shared pointer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found my answer. Actually what I was searching was pretty similar to this answer (thanks moooeeeep for his comment):

[Exposing a C++ class instance to a python embedded interpreter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8225934/exposing-a-c-class-instance-to-a-python-embedded-interpreter)

Following C++ class (Attention! default constructor is mandatory):

```
class TwoValues
{
public:
    TwoValues(void): iValue1(0), iValue2(0) {}
    TwoValues(int iValue1, int iValue2): iValue1(iValue1_), iValue2(iValue2_) {}

    int Addition(void) const {if (!this) return 0; return iValue1 + iValue2;}

public:
    int iValue1;
    int iValue2;
};
```

could be exposed by boost by following macro:

```
BOOST_PYTHON_MODULE(ModuleTestBoost)
{
class_<TwoValues>("TwoValues")
   .def("Addition",             &TWOVALUES::Addition)
   .add_property("Value1",      &TWOVALUES::iValue1)
   .add_property("Value2",      &TWOVALUES::iValue2);
};
```

In the other hand I have a python function defined in `python_script.py` which takes an instance of this class and do something. For example:

```
def wrapper_function(instance):
    result = instance.Addition()
    myfile = open(r"C:\...\testboostexample.txt", "w")
    output = 'First variable is {0}, second variable is {1} and finally the addition is {2}'.format(instance.Value1, instance.Value2, result)
    myfile .write(output)
    myfile .close()
```

Then in C++ side, I can call this function by sending at the same time the instance of my class, like this:

```
Py_Initialize();

try
    {
    TwoValues instance(5, 10);
    initModuleTestBoost();

    object python_script = import("python_script");
    object wrapper_function = python_script.attr("wrapper_function");
    wrapper_function(&instance);
    }
catch (error_already_set)
    {
    PyErr_Print();
    }

Py_Finalize();
```

Advantages:

- I don't need build any shared library or binary
- As I'm using Boost, I don't need to be worry about memory management
  & reference counting
- I don't use shared boost pointer (boost::shared_ptr) to point to the
  instance of my class

Answer (score 7):

As far as I know, there is no easy way to accomplish this.

To extend Python with C++ with neither a module nor an intermediate library, it would require dynamically loading a library, then importing the functions.  This approach is used by the [`ctypes`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/ctypes.html#module-ctypes) module.  To accomplish the same with C++, one would need to write a `ctypes`*-like* library that understood the C++ ABI for the target compiler(s).

To extend Python without introducing a module, an intermediate library could be created that provided a C API that wraps the C++ library.  This intermediate library could then be used in Python through `ctypes`.  While it does not provide the exact calling syntax and does introduce an intermediate library, it would likely be less effort than building a `ctypes`*-like* library that could interface directly with C++.

However, if an intermediate library is going to be introduced, it may be worthwhile to use Boost.Python, SWIG, or some other C++/Python language binding tool.  While many of these tools will introduce the extension via a module, they often provide cleaner calling conventions, better error checking in the binding process, and may be easier to maintain.

Comment: Very nice answer. Covers everything I wanted to say and more (so I'm not even going to answer ;)

Answer (score 0):

pybind11 provides `PYBIND11_EMBEDDED_MODULE`which can be used to export C++ class without creating of extension module.