# PyBind11: How to use a class as a data type

Tags: python, c++, pybind11, nanobind

How do I convert a C++ class into a 'data type', for instance, if I had a vector: `dog_vector`, I can convert it to a `py::array` and expose it to Python where it would be read as a Numpy array. How do I expose a class to Python, allowing for its methods to also be called from Python.

I am trying to create a callback function in Python which takes in a class defined in my C++ code i.e.

```py
# Python side
import myextension

def make_dog_bark(dog: myextension.Dog):
    dog.bark()
```

How do I convert a class into a data type that can be used as such in Python? If Dog was a vector, for instance, my C++ binding for the callback would have been:

```
make_dog_bark(py::array_t<int64_t>(dog_vector.size(), dog_vector.data()))
```

and I would use in Python as

```
def make_dog_bark(dog_vector: npt.npt.NDArray):
    print(dog_vector)
```

I'm not sure if this is clear. I have tried to keep the example minimal and avoid putting all the callback registering and stuff but I can add more information if required.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to expose a C++ class to Python without building a module](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18442403/how-to-expose-a-c-class-to-python-without-building-a-module)

Comment: I'm unclear why you tagged this (or your previous question) as Cython. Cython is an alternative binding generator to Pybind11 which you don't look to be using. I've removed the tags but just wanted to check I haven't missed anything

Comment: @DavidW My apologies. I tagged it as I assumed Cython users are likely to be well versed with Pybind. I guess that's not how the tags should work?

Comment: @Sand Thanks. Yeah it's a similar thing but their solution is for Boost/SWIG. I will try the `PYBIND11_EMBEDDED_MODULE` suggestion in the other answer. Thanks again.