# Pass python results to a C++ listbox

Tags: python, c++, listbox

I'm going to code in C++ and Python. I want Python to do a web crawling task and return the results to a C++ listbox. How can I grab the results from Python and pass them to the C++ part of my application? Only thing i see differences from [how to pass a value to c++ from python and back?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2613497/how-to-pass-a-value-to-c-from-python-and-back) then my question is that I'm asking how to grab results from python and add them in C++ listbox; for example,

p = subprocess.Popen(["/your/app"], //Yes app goes there //how about the results not the app itself?   stdin=subprocess.PIPE, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
output = p.communicate(input)[0]

listBox1.Items.Add(p); // p should add results from python. I didn't see this in the other site so I post this.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to pass a value to c++ from python and back?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2613497/how-to-pass-a-value-to-c-from-python-and-back)

Comment: Yeah i was wondering how to do pass value from python to c++

Answer (score 0):

As said Pavel Pája Halbich and msw in the other post, the proper solution is using PyObject.
If you want to have a two-way communication between C++ & Python, Boost Python would be interesting for you. Take a look at website [Boost Python](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_61_0/libs/python/doc/html/index.html),

This post would also be interesting:
[How to expose a C++ class to Python without building a module](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18442403/how-to-expose-a-c-class-to-python-without-building-a-module)